# MySQL PHP Search result with pagination

Tags: php, mysql, search, pagination

Creating a new project using php: retrieving data from mysql database using a search function (search.php) - added pagination to the search result on results page (find.php). Question is, when the first search is displayed, it shows the correct data; however, when i click on 2nd page (pagination button), it populates all the data again - not the term i searched for: Please help!

search.php

```
<form action="find.php" method="post">
<input name="search" type="search" autofocus><input type="submit" name="button">
</form>
```

find.php

```
<?php

include_once("config.php");


if(isset($_POST['button'])){ 
    $search=$_POST['search'];
}

$result = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM bra_list WHERE locations like '%{$search}%' $limit "); 
$row = mysql_num_rows($result);
$page_rows = 3;
$last = ceil($row/$page_rows);

if($last < 1){
    $last = 1;
}
$pagenum = 1;

if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    $pagenum = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['page']);
}

if ($pagenum < 1) { 
    $pagenum = 1; 
} else if ($pagenum > $last) { 
    $pagenum = $last; 
}

$limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows;

$result = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM bra_list WHERE locations like '%{$search}%' $limit ");  
$textline2 = "Page <b>$pagenum</b> of <b>$last</b>";


$paginationCtrls = '';

$self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

if($last != 1){
    if ($pagenum > 1) {
        $previous = $pagenum - 1;
        $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$self.'?page='.$previous.'">Previous</a>';
        for($i = $pagenum-4; $i < $pagenum; $i++){
            if($i > 0){
                $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$self.'?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
            }
        }
    }
    $paginationCtrls .= '<span class="current">'.$pagenum.'</span>';

    for($i = $pagenum+1; $i <= $last; $i++){
        $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$self.'?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
        if($i >= $pagenum+4){
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($pagenum != $last) {
        $next = $pagenum + 1;
        $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$self.'?page='.$next.'">Next</a> ';
    }
}

?>

<table border='1' cellpadding='10' style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>address</th>
<th>phone</th>
<th>email</th>
<th>website</th>
<th>locations</th>
<th>info</th>
</tr>

<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['address']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['phone']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['website']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['locations']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['info']; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
}

?>
```

Comment: the first query shouldn't contain a limit. the second should contain a limit and an offset

Answer (score -1):

You must have to set search term in pagination links. Try this.

```
<form action="find.php" method="post">
<input name="search" type="search" autofocus><input type="submit" name="button">
</form>
<?php

include_once("config.php");


if(isset($_POST['button'])){ 
    $search=$_POST['search'];
}


$result = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM bra_list WHERE locations like '%{$search}%' $limit "); 
$row = mysql_num_rows($result);
$page_rows = 3;
$last = ceil($row/$page_rows);

if($last < 1){
    $last = 1;
}
$pagenum = 1;

if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    $pagenum = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['page']);
}
// get search tearm from url
if(isset($_GET['search'])){ 
    $search=$_GET['search'];
}
if ($pagenum < 1) { 
    $pagenum = 1; 
} else if ($pagenum > $last) { 
    $pagenum = $last; 
}

$limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows;

$result = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM bra_list WHERE locations like '%{$search}%' $limit ");  
$textline2 = "Page <b>$pagenum</b> of <b>$last</b>";


$paginationCtrls = '';

$self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
// you must have to set search tearm in pagination links
if($last != 1){
    if ($pagenum > 1) {
        $previous = $pagenum - 1;
        $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$self.'?page='.$previous.'&search='.$search.'">Previous</a>';
        for($i = $pagenum-4; $i < $pagenum; $i++){
            if($i > 0){
                $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$self.'?page='.$i.'&search='.$search.'">'.$i.'</a>';
            }
        }
    }
    $paginationCtrls .= '<span class="current">'.$pagenum.'</span>';

    for($i = $pagenum+1; $i <= $last; $i++){
        $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$self.'?page='.$i.'&search='.$search.'">'.$i.'</a>';
        if($i >= $pagenum+4){
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($pagenum != $last) {
        $next = $pagenum + 1;
        $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$self.'?page='.$next.'&search='.$search.'">Next</a> ';
    }
}

?>

<table border='1' cellpadding='10' style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>address</th>
<th>phone</th>
<th>email</th>
<th>website</th>
<th>locations</th>
<th>info</th>
</tr>

<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['address']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['phone']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['website']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['locations']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['info']; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
}

?>
```

Comment: wont work, POST for the form, but the urls are GET

Comment: what is the problem with this ?

Comment: after the initial search using POST, the search term is now in the GET global for future pages

Comment: @Dagon [Just as I said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36637117/mysql-php-search-result-with-pagination#comment60869295_36637117) in comments up there, but nobody's listening to me. Maybe they'll listen to you ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry didn't notice you :-)

Comment: @Dagon I wasn't referring to you ;-) *Cheers, closing shop now*. Ciao bro.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i know bro, see you in a week on vacation

Comment: @Dagon You got it :-)